# Using functors without default constructors for stl containers

Tags: c++, stl, argument-passing, functor, default-constructor

I would like to use my own comparator for `std::set`, which needs a parameter to be passed to its constructor:

```
template <class T = double> class EpsCompare {
  public:
    EpsCompare(T input_eps) : _eps(input_eps) {};
    bool operator() (const T & element1, const T & element2) const {
       return ( round(element1*_eps) < round(element2*_eps) );
    }
    T _eps;
};
```

How do I pass this to the declaration of my set data type? I would like to do something like this:

```
std::set<double, EpsCompare<double>(1e-5)> myEpsSet;
```

This does not compile, so how else can it be done?

Comment: Pass an instance to the constructor: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set

Comment: You **will** get burnt by this comparator. Never. Ever. Ever. Use. An. Epsilon. When. Sorting. Numbers. Ever.

Comment: @n.m. Why? And I don't even think this here is an epsilon in the typical sense.

Comment: @Angew You are right, this is not a usual fuzzy comparison, my eyes see what they want, not what's written :( As for why, a fuzzy comparison is not a strict weak ordering, so the usual algorithms just won't work. Imagine a sequence of numbers, each one within epsilon of the next, but the extremes are far away; how would you sort them?

Comment: The second template parameter to set should be an appropriate  class, here it is an instance of a class (but not a class itself)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::set<double, EpsCompare<> > myEpsSet(EpsCompare<>(1e-5));
```

or

```
std::set<double, EpsCompare<double> > myEpsSet(EpsCompare<double>(1e-5));
```

Comment: Is there any reason to pass `EpsCompare<double>` as second parameter to `std::set` template?

Comment: @Slava, yes that is needed. Unlike function templates, template parameters are not deduced from the arguments used to construct an instance of a class template.

Comment: I do not follow. Needed for what? If you do not pass it to template, only to `std::set` ctor, what difference will it make?

Comment: @Slava The second template parameter of `std::set` sets he type of the comparator. By default, it's `std::less<T>` (where `T` is the first template parameter). But you don't want an to use object of type `std::less<double>`, you want an object of type `EpsCompare<double>`.

Comment: My problem was actually a bit more complex, since I did not try to call `myEpsSet` directly, but within a class declaration. But then using the same in the initializer of the new class constructor did the job:
`class Testclass {
public:
 std::set<double, EpsCompare<double> > myEpsSet;
 Testclass() : myEpsSet(EpsCompare<double>(1e-5)) {};
}
`

Comment: @Angew second template parameter sets comparator that would be used if you do not pass one to `std::set` constructor explicitly. As you do pass it, it does not really matter if you pass comparator as second template parameter or not.

Comment: @Slava Incorrect. The second template parameter controls the *type* of the comparator, the constructor parameter specifies the *instance* of the comparator to use. The type of that constructor parameter is the template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Something as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

template <class T = double> class EpsCompare {
  public:
    EpsCompare(T input_eps) : _eps(input_eps) {};
    bool operator() (const T & element1, const T & element2) const {
       return ( round(element1*_eps) < round(element2*_eps) );
    }
    T _eps;
};


int main() 
{
    std::set<double, EpsCompare<double>> myEpsSet(EpsCompare<double>(1e-5) );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass `eps` as parameter to `std::set` you have to make it part of template. You cannot use `double` as template parameter, so one of the solution to have power as template parameter:

```
template <class T, int power > class EpsCompare {
  public:
    EpsCompare() { eps = pow( 10, power ); }
    bool operator() (const T & element1, const T & element2) const {
       return ( round(element1*eps) < round(element2*eps) );
    }
  private:
       T eps;
};

std::set<double, EpsCompare<double,-5>> myEpsSet;
```

If you want to pass eps as parameter to EpsCompare constructor, you make it runtime so you cannot use it in template and pass your comparator to `std::set`:

```
std::set<double,EpsCompare<double>> myEpsSet( EpsCompare<double>( 1e-5 ) );
```

will be sufficient.

Comment: I had tried a similar solution before, but found this an unsatisfactory workaround considering that what I really want to pass is an interval size (might be 1.5 or something as well), not always just the number of digits...

Comment: Then you have to pass it at runtime, unless you find a way to specify it as multiple ints for example.